# Plot a square grid with a subset of squares marked using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Recently I have discovered pgfplots and I am impressed by the capabilities of this package. There is however one type of plots which I cannot figure out how to define conveniently using pgfplots.

Basically I would like to plot a square grid with a subset of squares marked (I'm sorry, as a new user I'm not allowed to post images). I am aware that I can follow/modify the example from the manual in which a closed shape is drawn:

```
% Preamble: \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.6}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[fill] coordinates
{(0,1) (1,2) (0,3) (-1,2)} --cycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I'm wondering - is it possible to define such plot passing only the **integer coordinates of squares** to mark, rather than lists of four precise corners of each square?

Comment: You have the `grid` option.

Comment: I'm not talking about the grid, but coordinate input.

Comment: the `rectangle` command needs only the left-down and right-up coordinates. You can try

    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,5}{
     \draw (0,0) rectangle (\x,\x);
    }

You can use other values to produce the non square rectangles.

Comment: @PrzemysławPietrzkiewicz: You can post a link to your image, then a user with enough rep can edit your question to include the picture.

Comment: @Sigur: I didn't know about the \foreach construct; it looks handy. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't sure if you wanted stacks or slabs, so here is both:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\usepackage{trimspaces}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\makeatletter
\def\trimspace#1{\trim@spaces@in{#1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\getslab}[2]{\checkdrawsquares(#1,#2)\trimspace\cachedata}

\newcommand{\drawstacks}[3]% fillheights, baroptions, gridoptions
{   \draw[#3] (0,0) grid (\gridwidth,\gridheight);
    \foreach \x [count=\c] in {#1}
    {   \fill[#2] (\c-1,0) rectangle (\c,\x);
    }
}

\newcommand{\drawslabs}[3]% dataarray, slaboptions, gridoptions
{   \draw[#3] (0,0) grid (\gridwidth,\gridheight);
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\gridwidth}
    { \foreach \y in {1,...,\gridheight}
        {   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\colnum}{\x}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rownum}{\gridheight+1-\y}
            \getslab{\rownum}{\colnum}
            \ifthenelse{\cachedata>0}
                {\fill[#2] (\x-1,\y-1) rectangle (\x,\y);}
                {}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\gridwidth}{13}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\gridheight}{7}

\newarray\drawsquares
\readarray{drawsquares}{%
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 &%
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &%
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &%
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 &%
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 &%
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &%
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1}
\dataheight=\gridwidth%

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawstacks{1,7,5,0,3,0,0,2,3,4,6,4,7}{red!50!gray,fill opacity=0.5,draw=red!50!gray,thick}{gray,densely dashed}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawslabs{drawsquares}{red!50!gray,fill opacity=0.5,draw=red!50!gray,thick}{gray,densely dashed}{red}{gray}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** I managed it, only forgot the `\expandafter` before `\csname` yesterday.

### Updated `\getslab`

```
\newcommand{\getslab}[3]{\expandafter\csname check#1\endcsname(#2,#3)\trimspace\cachedata}
```

### Updated `\drawslabs`

```
\newcommand{\drawslabs}[3]% arraname, slaboptions, gridoptions
{   \draw[#3] (0,0) grid (\gridwidth,\gridheight);
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\gridwidth}
    { \foreach \y in {1,...,\gridheight}
        {   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\colnum}{\x}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rownum}{\gridheight+1-\y}
            \getslab{#1}{\rownum}{\colnum}
            \ifthenelse{\cachedata>0}
                {\fill[#2] (\x-1,\y-1) rectangle (\x,\y);}
                {}
        }
    }
}
```

### New sample input

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\gridwidth}{13}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\gridheight}{7}

\newarray\drawsquares
\readarray{drawsquares}{%
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 &%
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &%
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &%
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 &%
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 &%
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &%
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1}
\dataheight=\gridwidth%

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawstacks{1,7,5,0,3,0,0,2,3,4,6,4,7}{red!50!gray,fill opacity=0.5,draw=red!50!gray,thick}{gray,densely dashed}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawslabs{drawsquares}{red!50!gray,fill opacity=0.5,draw=red!50!gray,thick}{gray,densely dashed}{red}{gray}
\end{tikzpicture}

\delarray\drawsquares% Deleting the old array; don't reuse names of deleted arrays!

% define a "new array" by just interchanging width and height

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\gridwidth}{7}% changed from 13 to 7
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\gridheight}{13}% changed from 7 to 13

\newarray\verticalarray% new name
\readarray{verticalarray}{%
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 &%
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &%
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &%
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 &%
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 &%
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &%
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1}
\dataheight=\gridwidth% similar array as before, but this time interpreted as 7x13 instead of 13x7

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawslabs{verticalarray}{red!50!gray,fill opacity=0.5,draw=red!50!gray,thick}{gray,densely dashed}{red}{gray}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

### New sample output (with `geometry` option `a3paper`)

[image]

Comment: I am genuinely impressed; this is exactly what I needed. Many thanks for your time!

Comment: Thanks! As I didn't explain how it works and hope that the code is well readable, please feel free to ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: You can also have a look **[at this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59055/fill-nodes-according-to-table-data-file)**, there I did something comparable to this problem.

Comment: I have just one question for now - do I understand correctly, that \drawslabs does not really make use of its first parameter, as the name of the array is hardcoded in form of "\checkdrawsquares" call? Is there any way to effectively parametrize \drawslabs with the array being drawn?

Comment: Yes, I tried to do something like `\check#1` which obviousely does not work. It should probably be something like `\csname check#1 \endcsname`. I'll try this tomorrow and let you know of the results.

Comment: I would really appreciate that. I cannot figure out how to feed various arrays to this routine one after another. Unfortunately I cannot run \readarray{drawsquares} before each time, because I need to put the calls into a tabular.

Comment: The updated code works flawlessly; many thanks! Could you please drop me a line on pietrzkiewicz at gmail com, so that I can credit you in Acknowledgements section of my thesis?