# Create a Shmoo plot with pgfplots/tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I'm interested in creating a Shmoo-plot using LaTeX. I have looked through the PGFplot-examples but couldn't find any that looked suitable as a starting template. Google produces nothing as well, and I don't wish to abuse Excel for obvious non-pretty reasons (although it is very easy for this kind of plot).

If a Shmoo-plot is unfamiliar to you, it is a two dimensional (presented as such at least) discrete plot looking something like this:

[image]

What I want to produce like the image above, although without the pass/fail text. Do you have any suggestions on how I should approach the problem? Sorry if this is a very simple question, I am a beginner in PGFplots and might have missed an easy solution.

edit: this is a more accurate image of what I'm trying to reproduce. This is almost exactly the style I'm looking for.

[image]

the input data formatting can be changed to fit any solution, so it is not considered a problem. For example, it can be (x, y, p/f) such as a simple four point set:

(1, 10, 1)
(1, 11, 0)
(2, 10, 1)
(2, 11, 0)

Comment: This could be something that can be easily coded for TikZ direct (e.g. a `\matrix`) or even a simple `tabular`. Especially if the *x* and *y* values are discrete like that. How does the input look like?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format

Comment: I'm not familiar with a `shmoo` plot.  But it looks straight-forward enough.  Do you have sample data that would be the source for such a graph?

Comment: If sample data is neccesary, it will be a three dimensional data set with an x-value, y-value and a discrete value (indicating pass/fail). A simple example with four points could look like: (1, 10, 1) (2, 10, 0) (1, 11, 1) (2, 11, 1). However, I can customize the formatting so not an issue.

Comment: After reconsidering this might be something for the `mesh` or the `surf` plot, though it seems the colors of the *z* values are assigned to an area between coordinates and not an area around coordinates.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirbel: this might be a possible (although not very pretty solution. That each point would have to be extrapolated to four points to build a box, and then adjust the viewer to receive the 2-dimensional look.

Comment: This could be a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73640/using-pgfplots-how-do-i-arrange-my-data-matrix-for-a-surface-plot-so-that-each

Comment: This could also be a duplicate of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68742/plot-a-square-grid-with-a-subset-of-squares-marked-using-pgfplots/68773#68773).

Comment: [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123719) might also be a starting point for a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got a result I was satisfied with, and I'm answering this to help any other poor EE-engineer if they get stuck with the same thing. This is a simple solution compared to the ones discussed in the comments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style={color=black}, minor grid style={color=black}}
\pgfplotsset{every  tick/.style={black,}}


\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
 xmin=7.5,
 xmax=52.5,
 ymin=0,
 axis on top,
 tick align=outside,
 tickpos=left,
 xtick=data,
 minor xtick={7.5,12.5,...,55},
 ytick={0,0.2,...,2.5},
 minor ytick={0.1,0.2,...,2.4},
 enlargelimits=false,
 axis background/.style={fill=green!30},
 yminorgrids,
 ymajorgrids,
 xminorgrids,
 xlabel=Frequency (MHz),
 ylabel=V$_{\text{DD}}$ (V)]
\addplot
[const plot mark mid,fill=red!30] 
coordinates
{
(5,0.7)
(10,0.8)
(15,0.9)
(20,1)
(25,1.1)
(30,1.2)
(35,1.3)
(40,1.4)
(45,1.5)
(50,1.6) 
(55,1.7)
} 
\closedcycle;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```