# Indexing issues with 2D arrays

Tags: tikz-pgf, environment-variables

I have a tikz code using values stored in a 1D array, here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def \myArray {{0,1,2,3}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \pgfmathsetmacro\x{\myArray[0]}
        \draw (0,0) node {\x};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So this one works OK for my complex code, but I could really improve it using 2D arrays and loops. Here is a Minimum Not Working Example of what it could look like :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def \myArray {{0,1}{2,3}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \pgfmathsetmacro\x{\myArray[1][1]}
        \draw (0,0) node {\x};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with this code, I'm expecting to have the value "3" displayed (2nd line, 2nd column).

Is there a way to do 2D array storage and indexing with latex/tikz ?

Comment: Yes, you can look at **[arrayjobx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/arrayjobx?lang=en)**. I wrote a few answers using it **[here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59055/fill-nodes-according-to-table-data-file/59759#59759)** and **[here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68742/plot-a-square-grid-with-a-subset-of-squares-marked-using-pgfplots/68773#68773)**.

Comment: Or you can go old school and use \csname myArray\x,\y\endcsname.  (I suspect trying to use [\x][\y] will be much harder.)

Comment: An alternative solution could be: [How to use values from a 2d array in a tikz picture ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288712/124842)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are keen on a change of syntax, with `expl3` it can be easily done:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definearray}{mm}
 {
  \seq_gclear_new:c { g_thomas_array_#1_seq }
  \seq_set_split:cnn { g_thomas_array_#1_seq } { ; } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\retrieve}{mmm}
 {
  \clist_item:en { \seq_item:cn { g_thomas_array_#1_seq } { #2 + 1 } } { #3 + 1 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { c }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_item:nn { e }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definearray{myarray}{0,1;2,3}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node {\retrieve{myarray}{1}{1}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The two `+1` are for starting indexing at 0, as usual for PGF arrays (`expl3` sequences and comma separated lists start at 1).

A different approach, with a different syntax:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definearray}{mm}
 {
  \tl_gclear_new:c { g_thomas_array_#1_tl }
  \tl_gset:cn { g_thomas_array_#1_tl } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\retrieve}{mmm}
 {
  \clist_item:en { \tl_item:cn { g_thomas_array_#1_tl } { #2 + 1 } } { #3 + 1 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_item:nn { e }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definearray{myarray}{{0,1}{2,3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node {\retrieve{myarray}{1}{1}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In either case, here's the output:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do the same using nested comma lists? Perhaps start with `\def\matrix{{1,2},{3,4}}` and then use `clist_item:cn {#1} {#2}` to get, for example, {1,2} and then after setting some new clist variable equal to this use #3 to get one of the two elements. Something like this could be used to access elements from multidimensional arrays stored as nested comma lists...

Comment: @TedBlack I'll add it.

Comment: Many thanks. Sorry for the repeated novice questions: no matter how hard I try something like  `\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {\clist_item:cn {#1} {#2}}` and then use `\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#3}` does not work. The program treats `\l_tmpa_clist` as a single token. My understanding of clists is obviously very poor but can you help me understand the main problem with my thinking?

Comment: @TedBlack Sorry, but `\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {\clist_item:cn {#1} {#2}}` is not going to work. For several reasons. Actually this is understatement…

Comment: Yes it definitely does not work! Sounds like I need to study this a lot more...